# Is it possible to learn sanskrit on your own?

Tags: theravada

I want to learn sanskrit so that I'll have an easier go at learning pali

Comment: I don't know, but Oppenheimer (the physicist) did it.

Comment: Introduction to Sanskrit, by Thomas Egenes, is a good place to start - for self-studying Sanskrit.

Comment: People say that Oppenheimer didn't study alone: [What is definitely known is that he didn’t start studying Sanskrit seriously until 1933, when he started studying with the renown Sanskrit scholar Arthur W. Ryder while he was a professor at Berkeley.](http://blog.nuclearsecrecy.com/2014/05/23/oppenheimer-gita/)